# Why does Web API parse a comma-separated int array in an action path correctly but cannot parse a comma-separated decimal array?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API project written in .NET Core 2.1.  I'm trying to create an action that can take an array of decimal values as a parameter.

If I define the parameter data type as `string[]` or `int[]` then when I call the action, passing in a comma-separated string, Web API is able to parse that into an array of strings or an array of ints.

However, if I change the data type of the parameter to `decimal[]` and call it again with the same comma-separated string, Web API strips out the commas and concatenates the values together to form a single large decimal.

Why does it split a comma-separated string correctly if the parameter is defined as an `int[]` but not if it's a `decimal[]`?

Example:

Here's my action:

```
[HttpGet("details/{shipmentDetailIds}")]
public async Task<List<ShipmentDetail>> GetByShipmentDetailIds(decimal[] shipmentDetailIds)
{
    ...
}
```

Here's what I'm passing in as an argument when I call it via Postman:
[image: Values passed in when calling via Postman]

Here's how the array is parsed in the action when I define the parameter as a decimal array:

[image: How the argument is parsed as a decimal array]

You can see it effectively stripped out the commas and concatenated the three numbers together into a single large decimal value.

But if I change the data type of the parameter to `int[]` and call it again from Postman with the same argument values, this time Web API parses the argument correctly, splitting it into three numbers:

[image: How the same argument is parsed as an int array]

Why the different behaviour when parsing the same argument as a decimal array and an int array?  And how can I get it to parse the comma-separated decimals correctly?

**EDIT:** I know I could get this to work by passing the array in the query string.  However, I'm updating an existing app where all the arguments are passed in the URL path, rather than the query string, so I'd like to continue to use the same convention.  Another alternative would be to use an integer array, since that works.  However, although the shipmentDetailIds currently appear to be integers the data type in the warehouse management system is decimal.  I would prefer to stick to the correct data type in case shipments start coming through with decimal-style shipmentDetailIds in future.

Comment: That certainly seems odd. If you include a single decimal place ("3215669.0,3215670.0,3215994.0") what does it do?

Comment: Is that how you are supposed to send an array with Postman? I thought you were supposed to have multiple entries. So here multiple `shipmentDetails` rows, each with it's own value.

Comment: I see you're in NZ.  (I recognized the image on your sig, and checked your profile.)  You will have thought of this, I'm sure, but could this relate to the Culture settings on your box, and the default parsing behavior from strings to numbers?  I'm wondering whether it's treating the comma as what in the US we call the "decimal point".

Comment: (I don't know NZ numeric-representation conventions, but it's a possibility that occurs to me.)

Comment: @AnnL.: I tried your suggestion of adding a single decimal place after each number in the comma-separated input string: `3215669.0,3215670.0,3215994.0`.  Web API doesn't parse that at all.  It doesn't throw an error but sees the input as an empty decimal array.

Comment: Interesting and strange! I will look into this more and get back to you!

Comment: You can refer to this case idea, which may be helpful to you: https://www.strathweb.com/2017/07/customizing-query-string-parameter-binding-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested comma separated number string as an integer array and it gives the error. Decimal array accepts string as one  big number, but only if 3 digits are  comma separated.

So I recomend you to use the only way that is known so far and it works if you want to send a number array as query params of GET url.

Change the action

```
[HttpGet("details")]
public async Task<List<ShipmentDetail>> GetByShipmentDetailIds([FromQuery] decimal[] shipmentDetailIds)
{
    ...
}
```

to use a postman GET  use this query string

```
...Details?shipmentDetailIds=1232&shipmentDetailIds=2335..and so on
```

If you still want to use comma separated string containing numbers, then make  action input parameter as a string type  and inside of the action use Split to convert string to array.

Comment: In the end I followed Serge's advice, sort of, and made the parameter a string array, then converted the string array to a decimal array inside the action.